# How to make <h2> element go up or be centered between this white space (shown in the picture)

Tags: html, css

CSS code for the website i've also put these two different elements inside Div and each img has a padding so it dosen't stick to the div border from above or from down
https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2xfD.png

```
h2{
  font-family: anteb;
  text-align: center;
  border: solid 0.4vw black;
  width: 15%;
  margin: auto;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding: .5%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 2vw; 
}
#thecont>img , #end{
width: 70%;
display:block;
margin:auto;
text-align: center;
padding: 5%;
```

}

Comment: In order for us to help you better, can you please update your question so that it shows your relevant code in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the **question itself**. It would also be helpful if you could let us know what you have tried so far to solve your problem. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: vertically or horizontally centering?

Comment: Can you post your HTML as well? It's easiest for us to give you a good answer if you post your code in a snippet in the question that we can run and see exactly what you're seeing, if possible.

Comment: no i want it to be centerted in the white space vertically its allready centered horizn

Comment: @mohamed_mostafa did you tried flexbox properties?

Comment: you cant see the pictures if i put it on snippit but ive iserted img for you to see

Comment: @VeenaK.Suresh no

Comment: use vertical-align:center;

Comment: guys look i've image that has padding i want the h2 element to go inside that padding of the upper element see the pic

Comment: why dont you give the same padding to the paragraph

Answer (score 0):

To make an item vertically and horizontally center you can make use of flexbox properties.
For the outer container of the element to be centered,

```
.outerContainer{
   display: -webkit-box;   /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6, BB7 */
   display: -ms-flexbox;  /* TWEENER - IE 10 */
   display: -webkit-flex; /* NEW - Safari 6.1+. iOS 7.1+, BB10 */
   display: flex; 
   justify-content:center;/* horizontal centering*/
   align-items:center; /* vertical centering */
   flex-direction:column; /* for making your child elements comes one after another in new lines*/
   height:200px;
   width:300px;
}
```